# How to reset Qt package on 22.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, 22.04, wayland, qt

(Not an advanced Linux user)

My GUI apps requiring the Qt library (Konsole, Wireshark, P4V etc) suddenly started seg faulting on start-up.

I tried `sudo apt reinstall '~i'`

I tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall qtwayland5`

but no luck.

Eventually I realized the apps couldn't find shared libraries to load Qt metadata because they were looking in `/usr/lib/plugins/` instead of `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/`.

A temporary solution was to set `QT_PLUGIN_PATH` to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/plugins/`.

However, I don't understand how this happened and I am concerned something else might be broken.

Given I already tried reinstalling every package, I'm not sure if Qt came with Ubuntu.

**How do I reset my Qt installation?**

(I have not done any Qt development, this is just the Qt library some apps use)